Выводить поля повторителя где селект имеет value как у выбранного в селекте на странице - ACF Pro WordPress
Мне нужно чтобы я на странице выбрал в селекте пункт и появилось соответствующее содержимое. Сейчас проблема получить value выбранного пункта чтобы сравнить его с тем пунктом, который в репиторе каждого цикла. Сейчас там выводятся данные только последнего цикла. Этот селект один и тот же - что на странице выводится что в админке в репитере - vybor_napravleniya.
Вот это селект на странице выводится:
 <?php if( have_rows('dobavit_kartochku') ): ?>
     
        <?php 
 
        $select = get_sub_field_object('vybor_napravleniya');
         
        $newvalue = $select['value'];

        ?>
         
        <select name="selectedop">
            <?php foreach( $select['choices'] as $k => $v ): ?>
                <option <?php echo ($k === $newvalue) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>
                    <?php echo $v; ?>
                    </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
 
<?php endif; ?>

Этот код выводит данные, которые должны зависеть от выбранного селекта сверху:
<?php if( have_rows('dobavit_kartochku')): ?>
        
        <div class="objects-slider">

<?php while ( have_rows('dobavit_kartochku') ) : the_row(); ?> 
<?php  
$field = get_sub_field_object( 'vybor_napravleniya' );
$value = $field['value'];
?>
<div class="slider-item">
<?php if( have_rows('dobavit_izobrazhenie') ): ?>
         
      <?php while ( have_rows( 'dobavit_izobrazhenie') ) : the_row(); ?>
      <?php if($value ==  $k):  ?>

     // Здесь выводится контент

      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?> 


И у меня selected="selected" не подставляется

selected="selected" появляется если while ( have_rows('dobavit_kartochku') ) : the_row(); добавить, н тогда несколько селектов выводится
